Some trades are disappeared in trade manifest when running strategy tester
I have write a simple pinescript strategy to perform entry and exit, in case of debugging, I have log the entry point's status after calling strategy.entry():
longId = str.format('Long {0}', longIndex)
strategy.entry(longId, strategy.long, qty)
strategy.exit('Exit', from_entry = longId, limit = limit, stop = stop, comment_profit = 'Win', comment_loss = 'Loss')
log.info('Long {0} entry at {1}, expected limit {2}, stop loss {3}, timeframe {4}', longIndex, close, limit, stop, tf)
longIndex := longIndex + 1

but there are some trades disappeared:

Is it require a payed plan to show all trades in the manifest ?
I have tried switching the timeframe used to run the strategy, only some of them can display all logged trades.

Strategy orders might be pending, and while log calls execute on every bar, those statements aren't equal.
